# Play Store current install vs. GCM device count

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-messaging

In play store console, I see 100k current devices but when I send pushes it is sent to 180k devices(80k delivered / 100k stored).

Play store docs say `active devices` for current installs. What does it really mean? When a device become `inactive`?

When I broadcast push, GCM says 180k OK response. Do I really sent 180k push notification message? How many users do I really have? Can inactive devices still get push notification?

Note that app is published in only Play store.

Comment: normally when the user uninstall the app becomes "inactive"... BTW, you could also have users installing your app outside the Play Store. Even if you didn't publish outside the PS, the apk can be easily remove from the mobile with root access and uploaded in forums, any website, etc

Comment: Are you receiving any canonical responses when sending those messages? Could be that you are also sending messages to tokens that are no longer valid.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla i don't think thats the case. even if its published in those ways, percentage is too high. ArthurThompson I'm getting canonical responses and merging/uptaing users but their percentage is too low.

Answer (score 0):

Inactive means that the device hasn't pinged Google Play for some period of time (I think a week), or it has been uninstalled from said device. An inactive device in such a case could get a ping from GCM, but it seems unlikely that there would be 80% of users with an old device that received this ping.

I suspect that for some reason duplicate messages have been sent, perhaps as a result of a poor connection, or other similar reason.

I don't think a device installed outside of Google Play would have a GCM ping return, but that is a third possibility. Again, it doesn't seem like it would cover 80%, but it could.

Comment: Yeah i think there is a time period for inactivity but I couldn't find it in any docs. a week, a month or whatever. I'm searching for exact explanation for inactivity.